Sitecore ADM tool to remove historical data is giving exception
We are using Sitecore ADM tool 9.3.3 version integrated with the Sitecore 9.3 version. We are trying to remove historical data from 2018 to 2023. When we try to execute this to remove a single contact by ID, and remove historical data by passing the date range for both the options we are getting the below exception. Please suggest what could be the issue.
2024-11-14 03:01:01.083 +00:00 [Information] RemoveContactsData operation was requested for 1 contacts.
2024-11-14 03:01:01.099 +00:00 [Information] RemoveManager: StopRunningTasksAndClearStorage operation was requested.
2024-11-14 03:10:43.218 +00:00 [Error] Exception has been thrown during executing query DeleteAllTasksQuery
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.


By the look of it your xDB has grown considerably over time which now results in the SQL timeout error and I suspect that neither server resource boosting nor increasing number of processing threads for Sitecore ADM will help here.
Therefore, I would recommend running the direct SQL queries to clean up your data.
Here is an example SQL script to delete interactions older than a certain date.

Thanks for the response and suggestion, yes, we have already done with data cleanup using direct SQL queries.
